# PyGame: Use SDL2 to render a pixel

Tags: python, pygame

I want to render a singular green pixel in PyGame with SDL2. This is my current code:

```py
import pygame
import pygame._sdl2

SCREEN_W = 800
SCREEN_H = 800

pygame.init()

pygame_screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_W, SCREEN_H), vsync=0, flags=pygame.SCALED)
window = pygame._sdl2.Window.from_display_module()

renderer = pygame._sdl2.Renderer.from_window(window)
renderer.draw_color = (0, 255, 0, 255)  # Set the draw color to green

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

scale_factor = 1

# Create a green surface
green_pixel = pygame.Surface((scale_factor, scale_factor))
green_pixel.fill((0, 255, 0, 255))

use_sdl2 = True

while True:
    msec = clock.tick(60)
    pygame_screen.fill((0, 0, 0))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()

    if use_sdl2:
        renderer.clear()
        dest_rect = pygame.rect.Rect(100, 100, scale_factor, scale_factor)
        renderer.blit(green_pixel, dest_rect)
        renderer.present()
    else:
        dest_rect = pygame.rect.Rect(100, 100, scale_factor, scale_factor)
        pygame_screen.blit(green_pixel, dest_rect)
        pygame.display.flip()
```

This gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/harald-yoga/Documents/Projects/Python/game-engine/src/game_engine/main.py", line 37, in <module>
    renderer.blit(green_pixel, dest_rect)
  File "src_c/cython/pygame/_sdl2/video.pyx", line 1166, in pygame._sdl2.video.Renderer.blit
  File "src_c/cython/pygame/_sdl2/video.pyx", line 1179, in pygame._sdl2.video.Renderer.blit
TypeError: source must be drawable
```

The non-SDL2 version (use_sdl2 = False) works fine and renders a green pixel at x: 100, y: 100. What am I doing wrong with the SDL version?

Answer (score 3):

SDL2 `blit` method usually requires requires a texture rather than a surface. `pygame.Surface` does not work with SDL2's rendering functions. Fix it by converting `pygame.Surface` into a texture. Here is the new code:

```py
# ... [previous code] ...

# Create a green surface
green_pixel = pygame.Surface((scale_factor, scale_factor))
green_pixel.fill((0, 255, 0, 255))

# Convert the surface to a texture
green_pixel_texture = renderer.create_texture_from_surface(green_pixel)

use_sdl2 = True

while True:
    # Previous code in the loop here

    if use_sdl2:
        renderer.clear()
        dest_rect = pygame.rect.Rect(100, 100, scale_factor, scale_factor)
        renderer.copy(green_pixel_texture, dstrect=dest_rect)  # Use copy instead of blit
        renderer.present()
    else:
        # Not SDL2 rendering code
```